# What is `init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)` annotation?

Tags: types, elm, elm-architecture

In [official Elm website](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/http.html) there is a `init` function definition I don't understand:

```
init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init _ =
  ( Loading
  , Http.get
      { url = "https://elm-lang.org/assets/public-opinion.txt"
      , expect = Http.expectString GotText
      }
  )
```

So `init` function returns a `tuple`, then why not define its notation as:

```
init: (Model, Cmd Msg)
```

But in their sample `init` returns a function that returns a `tuple`. Is this true?

And how to read `()` in `init : () -> (Model, Cmd Msg)`? For example can I say from anything return a tuple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `init` is a function. `()` is called the "unit" type. It's a type that has only one value, `()`, which is also called "unit".

Now I'm sure you're asking "Well that seems pretty useless. What's the point of having a function argument that can ever only be one thing?". The answer is that it's very useful if you write something generic that *might* take *something*, but don't always have to.

In this case, `Browser.element` specifies that `init` should have the type `flags -> ( model, Cmd msg )`, where `flags` is a type variable that can be anything. Since `Browser.element` does not constrain `flags` in any other way, you can replace it with whatever you want, and it should still compile.

Note however that `Browser.element` is a bit magic. At runtime, Elm will look at the type you've assigned to `flags` and expect you to pass it a value of that type from JavaScript. If you don't, this is one of very few instances where Elm will fail at runtime (although, technically, it will fail before any of your Elm code runs because you've made a mistake on the JavaScript-side). Specifying `()` here means you're not expecting any flags.

How flags work are explained in more detail [in the guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/flags.html)